# An exercise of infinite sets

Tags: set-theory

I have to proof that if A is an infinite set, then $P(P(A))$ has a countable set. They ask me to do it without using the Axiom of Choice

Comment: "*countable set*" do you mean a countably infinite set?  Some authors allow finite sets to also receive the label of "countable" which makes this incredibly trivial... $\emptyset$ is an element of your set and is countable.

Comment: Yes, I mean to have a countably infinite subset

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by *countable* you actually mean *countably infinite*.

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb N$ consider the set $\{F\in\wp(A):|F|=n\}$.

Comment: I am having trouble translating that into words, but I think you are saying if $G_n$ is the set of subsets of $A$ with $n$ elements, implying  $G_n$ is a subset of $P(A)$, then $\{G_1,G_2,G_3,\ldots\}$ is a countably infinite subset of $P(P(A))$

Comment: @Henry: Given the somewhat unsatisfactory nature of the question, I didn’t want to make it quite that explicit, but yes (though for me there’s also a $G_0$).

Comment: @BrianMoehring: True but irrelevant. We’re asked only to show that there is an injection from $\omega$ into $\wp(\wp(A))$, i.e., that $\wp(\wp(A))$ is Dedekind infinite.